# webView is not working in openjfx 12 from eclipse maven project

Tags: javafx-8

I've used Java 8 to create JavaFX venture in which I utilized webview for HTML substance and it is JavaFX expert task. When I try to move to OpenJDK 12 from Java 8 it stops working. What's more, it returns the underneath blunder:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class
>   com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView (in unnamed module @0x2145b572)
>   cannot access class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup (in module
>   javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export
>   com.sun.javafx.sg.prism to unnamed module @0x2145b572

Comment: Are you adding `javafx.web` to the module path? Are you using the JavaFX Maven plugin?

Comment: i have used javafx-controls, javafx-web, javafx-graphics, javafx-swing dependencies.

Comment: And what plugin are you using to run the project?

Comment: No plug-ins, it is just created in eclipse and running by using main method.

Comment: Then you are missing the VM arguments. See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse.

Comment: VM Arguments also set properly :  -Djava.library.path=ext\windows64 --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Comment: Not "properly", you are missing `javafx.web` from `--add-modules`.

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to VM arguments to load all libraries and it will work.

-Djava.library.path=ext\windows64 --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.graphics,javafx.media